# Git pre-commit hook to detect and block NSLog debug calls

Tags: iphone, objective-c, git

How would I create a git pre-commit hook that blocks commits with

```
NSLog(@"random debug stuff");
```

but skips over

```
//NSLog(@"useful to keep around");
```

Answer (score 0):

You are going to need to create your own logging system where you can specify the level of the message (error, warning, info or debug) and then ignore debug calls when you are not in debug mode (i.e. `-DDEBUG` not passed to compiler), or whenever some other compiler define is set or even at runtime using some configuration setting.

It's not clear to me how a git pre-commit hook would work at all in this situation as the state of your commits has nothing to do with what stage your app is at in terms of development.

Comment: Hey thanks for the idea, but we already have a wrapper for NSLog. My question arose from wanting to automatically enforce compliance in a team environment. (imagine an intern or random team member who sometimes accidentally leaves debug logs in the code when commit-ing)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [.pch file](http://www.cimgf.com/2010/05/02/my-current-prefix-pch-file/) Marcus Zarra published quite a some time ago, I use it in every project

Among other things it contain `NSLog` replacement called `DLog`, the benefit of using it is it leverages built in `DEUBUG` preprocessor macros to disable `NSLog` in production

Just include following code into YourProject.pch file:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
  #define DLog(...) NSLog(@"%s %@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, [NSString stringWithFormat:__VA_ARGS__])
  #define ALog(...) [[NSAssertionHandler currentHandler] handleFailureInFunction:[NSString stringWithCString:__PRETTY_FUNCTION__ encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] file:[NSString stringWithCString:__FILE__ encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] lineNumber:__LINE__ description:__VA_ARGS__]
#else
  #define DLog(...) do { } while (0)
  #ifndef NS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS
    #define NS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS
  #endif
  #define ALog(...) NSLog(@"%s %@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, [NSString stringWithFormat:__VA_ARGS__])
#endif

#define ZAssert(condition, ...) do { if (!(condition)) { ALog(__VA_ARGS__); }} while(0)
```

Comment: I added these lines to my project.pch file but i don't see any log statements in All output window. Pls help.

Comment: It is possible that you have not defined DEBUG, try setting up a new project to see if it works there